# Something like if in css

Tags: javascript, css

Is there something like IF in css?
what i want to do is I want to set image width, if it is more then 700px I need to set it to 700, but if it is less, I need to leave it alone and set only 5px margin around it.

is this doable with css, or I need tu use javaScript?

Comment: Would `max-width:700px` do what you need?

Comment: Two options, if the size changes based on the screen resolution use a `@media` query, otherwise you should probably use percent positioning rather than fixed values, or use `calc()`

Comment: max-width works, but i also need margin for smaller images, so larger ones also have margin if I set margin to smaller ones and so they have spaces in sides which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max-width` property.

```
img {
    max-width: 700px;
}
```

When it comes to `margin` I don't have a clue, yet. I'll try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Set `max-width: 700px;` the margin you have to do in javascript.

You can set the margin on the window.resize event something like this:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if("your-element-width">=700){
     //remove your margin here
     }else{
     //add margin here
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 700px) {
   /* Styles for screen below 700px you can set your  margins*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 700px) 
{
  /* Styles for screen above 700px you can set without margins*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
   max-width: 700px;
}
```

Something like that?
[More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/CSS/max-width)

Comment: no, i have only img selector to operate with, max width is 700px but i need to add margins for smaller ones, so css is
`img {max-width:700px; margin: 10px;}`

Answer (score 0):

There is no IF in css. You can use javascript to achieve it or use max-width:700px.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use JavaScipt you can do it with the `max-width` property.

**CSS:**

```
img {
    max-width: 700px;
}
```

You can also use media queries for modifying elements for different screen widths if needed.

**CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 700px) {
   /* Styles */
}
```

Comment: no, i can't because i need margin for smaller ones than 700px, so margin also applies to large images and i have blank space from parent till image.

Comment: In this case it's probably best you go with Igle's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use @ media with a resolution

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {}
```

more  help : 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp